# How to use onclicklistener

Tags: android

I am trying to use an onclick listener on radio buttons to update a spinner I have. The default numbers in the spinner will be 15, 25, 35, and 45. When you select the KG radio button I want it to change to 8, 15, and 20. I have the following:

```
public class PlateCalc_Tab extends Activity 
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.platecalc_tab);

    RadioButton weightSettingLB = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.weightSettingLB);
    RadioButton weightSettingKG = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.weightSettingKG);

    weightSettingLB.setChecked(true);

    weightSettingLB.setOnClickListener(updateToLB);
    weightSettingKG.setOnClickListener(updateToKG);

    List<String> weightOfBarArray =  new ArrayList<String>();

    weightOfBarArray.add("15");
    weightOfBarArray.add("25");
    weightOfBarArray.add("35");
    weightOfBarArray.add("45");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, weightOfBarArray);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner weightOfBarSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.weightOfBarSpinner);
    weightOfBarSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

View.OnClickListener updateToKG = new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View view)
    {

    }
};
```

This code currently works. When I enter the following code into my onclick listener I get an error.

```
View.OnClickListener updateToKG = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        List<String> weightOfBarArray =  new ArrayList<String>();

        weightOfBarArray.add("8");
        weightOfBarArray.add("15");
        weightOfBarArray.add("20");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, weightOfBarArray);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner weightOfBarSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.weightOfBarSpinner);
        weightOfBarSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
};
```

I get "Cannot Resolve Constructor" @ this line:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, weightOfBarArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the array adapter initialization like below.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PlateCalc_Tab.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, weightOfBarArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(v.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, weightOfBarArray);